# Is there any config setting in nodejs to check every ajaxcall ( some thing like zend predispatcher)

Tags: node.js, jquery, express, npm

I have a task in which i need to check every api call for authentication purpose( does api call have api key ) then call api and return response of api else return error message.

My task flow is some like this,

1(Front end)- call an api ( www.myurl.com/users/getusers ) using ajax with apikey
2-(back end nodejs) - check call have apikey , if exist then got to user/getusers and return response.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just put an express middleware in front?

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  if (req.headers['your api key'] == 'some value') return next();

  res.send(401);
});
```

or if you want it in front of a specific route:

```
app.get('/yoururl', check, function(req, res, next) {
  // perform db action
  res.send(200);
});

function check(req, res, next) {
  // call next() on success next(err) if err
  // or res.send(401) or similar
}
```